# Select2 with textarea

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

How can I use a textarea instead of the default text input when using select2?

I've tried changing the `input` tag to a `textarea` tag, but it seems that after the select2 js initialization is done, the element is converted to an input element.

The reason I want a textarea is because I want to signify to my users that they'll be choosing many items, so having multiple rows will be useful for my intentions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to?  You can set the height using css

```
.select2-container, .select2-choices { height: 200px;}
```

**Edit**: or even better you can just style a class on your input before you apply .select2() to it and the container will automatically append that class to the container. You can then make it look like a textarea.